# Apex `if (Boolean) `. Null exception virtually renders this check useless and unsafe

Tags: apex, aura, null-pointer, boolean

Being that an `if (booleanVariable)` check, where `booleanVariable` is `null`, throws a `NullPointerException`, it would seem that this check is unsafe. If so why would Apex allow it?

This is especially true when coming from Aura, where a checkbox before being checked or unchecked will be undefined (Yes, I know I can do `default="false"`).

For now in Apex I can do `booleanVariable = booleanVariable == true;` and then do the `if (booleanVariable)` check. For obvious reasons this is annoying.

But why Apex, why? Why allow the `if (booleanVariable)` check in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's allowed because a Boolean is already a Boolean; the syntax for an if statement reads `if(condition)`, where condition is a Boolean value. It's considered a best practice to always initialize your variables (e.g. read [Say No To Null](https://elegantcode.com/2010/05/01/say-no-to-null/)). In the majority of cases, nulls are handled automatically, but developers should take care of situations where it may have been null, mostly by making sure they always initialize data. The compiler cannot usually tell for certain if a value might be null, so the safest thing to do is to allow it to compile.

Comment: Great article. Then I guess the bigger question is why allow Booleans to be null or why throw the exception where null? I can initialize code coming from apex itself. But where my `@AuraHandled` has a `Boolean` argument, then I'm at the mercy of Aura. Unless of course I set a default.

Comment: @shmuels Because (a) all objects are allowed to be null, just like Java, and (b) because null values indicate an unknown value. For practical purposes, you *should* set default values in Aura, too. It's irresponsible to leave uninitialized values.

Comment: Note also Apex REST use case wherein deserialized Json into custom Apex types can easily yield null values for Booleans

Comment: @cropredy Yes, there's places where it can happen. Developers should be aware of this and plan accordingly. Still, if you have full control over the moving parts, one should prefer to avoid nulls as much as possible. A good portion of null checks can be avoided with a little extra care.

Comment: I wish my colleagues would read 'Say No to Null' - I've seen code littered with null checks that make figuring out what the method does nigh impossible (forest from trees).